# webRTC stream not showing in video element

Tags: reactjs, electron, webrtc

I'm trying to build a remote desktop controller app using **webRTC**, **electron** & **react**. Everything is working just fine (mouse movement and clicks) except for the part when the screen is shared. It's not displaying in the video element.

the offer and answer are being satisfied. *However, The `.ontrack()` method is not getting called*

this is

> App.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import './App.css';

const socket = io('https://da79-154-184-168-205.ngrok-free.app/remote-ctrl');

const App = () => {
    const videoRef = useRef();
    const rtcPeerConnection = useRef(
        new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [
                { urls: 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com' },
                { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
            ],
        })
    );
    const [selectedScreen, setSelectedScreen] = useState(1);

    const handleStream = (selectedScreen, stream) => {
        console.log('selected screen', selectedScreen);
        setSelectedScreen(selectedScreen);
        socket.emit('selectedScreen', selectedScreen);

        rtcPeerConnection.current.onicecandidate = (e) => {
            if (e.candidate) {
                console.log('sending icecandidate');
                socket.emit('icecandidate', e.candidate);
            }
        };
        console.log('stream', stream);
        console.log('track', stream.getTracks()[0]);
        rtcPeerConnection.current.addTrack(stream.getTracks()[0], stream);
    };

    const getUserMedia = async (constraints) => {
        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
                constraints
            );
            rtcPeerConnection.current
                .createOffer({
                    offerToReceiveAudio: false,
                    offerToReceiveVideo: true,
                })
                .then((sdp) => {
                    rtcPeerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(sdp);
                    console.log('sending offer');
                    socket.emit('offer', sdp);
                });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const getStream = async (selectedScreen) => {
            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    audio: false,
                    video: {
                        mandatory: {
                            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                            chromeMediaSourceId: selectedScreen.id,
                        },
                    },
                });
                handleStream(selectedScreen, stream);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        };

        const handleOffer = (offerSDP) => {
            console.log('received offer');
            rtcPeerConnection.current
                .setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offerSDP))
                .then(() => {
                    rtcPeerConnection.current.createAnswer().then((sdp) => {
                        rtcPeerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(sdp);
                        console.log('sending answer');
                        socket.emit('answer', sdp);
                    });
                });
        };

        const handleAnswer = (answerSDP) => {
            console.log('received answer');
            rtcPeerConnection.current.setRemoteDescription(
                new RTCSessionDescription(answerSDP)
            );
        };

        const handleIceCandidate = (icecandidate) => {
            rtcPeerConnection.current.addIceCandidate(
                new RTCIceCandidate(icecandidate)
            );
        };

        const handleIceConnectionStateChange = (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        };

        const handleTrack = (e) => {
            console.log('onTrack', e.streams);
            videoRef.current.srcObject = e.streams[0];
            videoRef.current.onloadedmetadata = (e) => videoRef.current.play();
        };

        const handleSelectedScreen = (selectedScreen) => {
            setSelectedScreen(selectedScreen);
        };

        (window.electronAPI &&
            window.electronAPI.getScreenId((event, screenId) => {
                console.log('Renderer...', screenId);
                getStream(screenId);
            })) ||
            getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });

        socket.on('offer', handleOffer);
        socket.on('answer', handleAnswer);
        socket.on('icecandidate', handleIceCandidate);
        rtcPeerConnection.current.onicecandidate = (e) => {
            if (e.candidate) socket.emit('icecandidate', e.candidate);
        };
        rtcPeerConnection.current.oniceconnectionstatechange =
            handleIceConnectionStateChange;
        rtcPeerConnection.current.ontrack = handleTrack;
        socket.on('selectedScreen', handleSelectedScreen);

        return () => {
            socket.off('offer', handleOffer);
            socket.off('answer', handleAnswer);
            socket.off('icecandidate', handleIceCandidate);
            rtcPeerConnection.current.onicecandidate = null;
            rtcPeerConnection.current.oniceconnectionstatechange = null;
            rtcPeerConnection.current.ontrack = null;
            socket.off('selectedScreen', handleSelectedScreen);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleMouseClick = () => {
        socket.emit('mouse_click', {});
    };

    const handleMouseMove = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
        socket.emit('mouse_move', {
            clientX,
            clientY,
            clientWidth: window.innerWidth,
            clientHeight: window.innerHeight,
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <div
                onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
                onClick={handleMouseClick}
                className='video-container'>
                <video ref={videoRef} className='video'>
                    video not available
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

this is

> main.js

```
const {
    app,
    BrowserWindow,
    desktopCapturer,
    ipcMain,
    Menu,
    powerMonitor,
} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const robot = require('@jitsi/robotjs');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const { screen } = require('electron');
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');

const expressApp = express();
const httpServer = createServer(expressApp);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    origin: '*',
});

let availableScreens;
let mainWindow;
let clientSelectedScreen;
let displays;

expressApp.use(express.static(__dirname));

expressApp.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('req path...', req.path);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

expressApp.set('port', 4000);
expressApp.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

expressApp.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
    );
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'X-Requested-With,content-type'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

httpServer.listen(4000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('listening.....');
});

const connections = io.of('/remote-ctrl');

connections.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('connection established');

    socket.on('offer', (sdp) => {
        console.log('routing offer');
        // send to the electron app
        socket.broadcast.emit('offer', sdp);
    });

    socket.on('answer', (sdp) => {
        console.log('routing answer');
        // send to the electron app
        socket.broadcast.emit('answer', sdp);
    });

    socket.on('icecandidate', (icecandidate) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('icecandidate', icecandidate);
    });

    socket.on('selectedScreen', (selectedScreen) => {
        clientSelectedScreen = selectedScreen;

        socket.broadcast.emit('selectedScreen', clientSelectedScreen);
    });

    socket.on(
        'mouse_move',
        ({ clientX, clientY, clientWidth, clientHeight }) => {
            const {
                displaySize: { width, height },
            } = clientSelectedScreen;
            const ratioX = width / clientWidth;
            const ratioY = height / clientHeight;

            const hostX = clientX * ratioX;
            const hostY = clientY * ratioY;

            robot.moveMouse(hostX, hostY);
        }
    );

    socket.on('mouse_click', ({ button }) => {
        robot.mouseClick('left', false); // true means double-click
    });
});

const sendSelectedScreen = (item) => {
    const displaySize = displays.filter(
        (display) => `${display.id}` === item.display_id
    )[0].size;

    mainWindow.webContents.send('SET_SOURCE_ID', {
        id: item.id,
        displaySize,
    });
};

const createTray = () => {
    const screensMenu = availableScreens.map((item) => {
        return {
            label: item.name,
            click: () => {
                sendSelectedScreen(item);
            },
        };
    });

    const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: app.name,
            submenu: [{ role: 'quit' }],
        },
        {
            label: 'Screens',
            submenu: screensMenu,
        },
    ]);

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
};

const createWindow = () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
    });

    ipcMain.on('set-size', (event, size) => {
        const { width, height } = size;
        try {
            console.log('electron dim..', width, height);
            // mainWindow.setSize(width, height || 500, true)
            !isNaN(height) && mainWindow.setSize(width, height, false);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL('https://da79-154-184-168-205.ngrok-free.app/');

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        displays = screen.getAllDisplays();

        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.setPosition(0, 0);

        desktopCapturer
            .getSources({
                types: ['screen', 'window'],
                // types: ['window', 'screen']
            })
            .then((sources) => {
                sendSelectedScreen(sources[0]);
                availableScreens = sources;
                createTray();
            });
    });

    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

and this is

> preload.js

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    setSize: (size) => ipcRenderer.send('set-size', size),
    getScreenId: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('SET_SOURCE_ID', callback)
})
```